# Upload CSV file in lightning component,but I have to click the button twice to insert the data

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to up load CSV file to create new quotelineItem records in lightning component.And I create a new action button link to my component in the quote page,after I upload my csv,I click the import button.but first time it didn't work,after I click any button second time,it works.I write many console.log,i find first time it stop before action.setCallback(this, function(response),and second time that function work,I don't know why.

controller

```
({
handleFilesChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var fileName = 'No File Selected..';
    if (event.getSource().get("v.files").length > 0) {
        fileName = event.getSource().get("v.files")[0]['name'];

    }
    component.set("v.fileName", fileName);
},
CreateRecord: function (component, event, helper) {
    var fileInput = component.find("file").get("v.files");
    var file = fileInput[0];
    //alert(file);
    if (file) {
    console.log("File");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        console.log("EVT FN");
        var csv = evt.target.result;
        console.log('@@@ csv file contains'+ csv);
        var result = helper.CSV2JSON(component,csv);
        console.log('@@@ result = ' + result);
        //console.log('@@@ Result = '+JSON.parse(result));
        helper.CreateAccount(component,result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("error reading file");
    }
}

}})
```

Helper

```
({
CSV2JSON: function (component,csv) {
console.log('@@@ Incoming csv = ' + csv);

    //var array = [];
    var arr = []; 

    arr =  csv.split('\n');;
    //console.log('@@@ Array  = '+array);
    console.log('@@@ arr = '+arr);
    arr.pop();
    var jsonObj = [];
    var headers = arr[0].split(',');
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var data = arr[i].split(',');
        var obj = {};
        for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            obj[headers[j].trim()] = data[j].trim();
            //console.log('@@@ obj headers = ' + obj[headers[j].trim()]);
        }
        jsonObj.push(obj);
    }
    var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    console.log('@@@ json = '+ json);
    return json;


},

CreateAccount : function (component,jsonstr){
 console.log('@@@ jsonstr' + jsonstr);
 var action = component.get("c.insertData"); 
    action.setParams({
            "strfromlex" : jsonstr
        });
    console.log("setParams has actived");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        console.log('@@@ SetCallback !');
        var state = response.getState();
        //alert(state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {              
        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                "type": "success",
                "message": "QuoteLineItems have imported."
            });
            resultsToast.fire();      
            var wasDismissed = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
            wasDismissed.fire();            
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
                 alert('Unknown');
            }
        }
    }); 
    $A.enqueueAction(action);}})
```

cmp

```
<aura:component controller="FileUploadController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
<aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" />
<aura:attribute name="fileName" type="String" default="No File Selected.." />
<lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
<div class="page-section page-header">
</div>
<lightning:input aura:id="file" 
                 onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange}" 
                 type="file" 
                 name="file" 
                 accept=".csv"
                 multiple="false"/>
<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="slds-text-body_middle slds-text-color_blue">{!v.fileName} </div>
<button style="margin-top:10px;" class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.CreateRecord}">导入CSV文件<button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you have written is all correct the main thing creating trouble for is the `FileReader.onload` callback method, in this callback you are making the request to the server.

So put this inside the `setTimeout` like this, this should solve your problem for clicking the button twice to make the server side call inside a callback.

So replace your serverside method call from the callback  like below with `setTimeout`:

```
window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){
  helper.CreateAccount(component,result);
}), 10);
```

Comment: itzmukeshy7，you save my life!!!!THANKS

Comment: @J.Who, are you still facing any issues even with this?

Comment: No,thanks.I'm a rookie.Just graduate from school.^_^